# Probability of winning in a sweepstake with multiple prizes

Tags: probability

**The Problem:**

Imagine that “n” distinct individuals participated in a sweepstake where “k” random draws will be made for a $10 gift card in each draw. Each individual can win nothing or 1 gift card only, i.e., an individual cannot win more than 1 gift card. Thus, if an individual wins a card in any of the draws, that individual is not entered into subsequent draws.

Find an expression for the probability of an individual's winning a gift card.

**My Approach:**

Since the number of names entered for each draw decreases by 1 after each draw, I could not find an easy way to compute the probability of an individual's not winning anything, as otherwise I could've subtracted that probability from 1 to get the probability of winning a card. So, I went draw by draw, in the hope of adding the probabilities across the "k" draws to get to the answer. However, the method I used led me to the same probability of winning, 1/n, from each draw. For instance, I arrived at the probability expression for winning in the 4th draw by multiplying the independent probability of winning in that draw by the probabilities of not winning in all of the previous draws = 1/(n-3) * (n-1)/n * (n-2)/(n-1) * (n-3)/(n-2) = 1/n. Here, 1/(n-3) is the independent probability of winning in the 4th draw, (n-1)/n is the probability of not winning in the 1st draw, (n-2)/(n-1) is the probability of not winning in the 2nd draw, and (n-3)/(n-2) is the probability of not winning in the 3rd draw.

**My questions:**

1. Am I correct in my approach, especially, in treating this as a compound/conditional probability issue where all previous draws of not winning must be factored in? Did I do the computation for the 4th draw correctly?
2. How can I derive an expression for the (compound) probability of winning in the kth draw? I was able to prove that would be 1/n also with the assumption that the compound probability of winning in the (k-1)th draw is 1/n which begs for a proof also. Without a formal proof for an expression for the generic "ith" draw, where 1<i<k, I cannot quite add the probabilities across the draws to arrive at the probability of winning a card.

Reasons I have doubts about my results are I'm a bit rusty on my probability solving skills, and I'm getting the rather surprising result that the probability of winning is exactly the same in every draw despite the fact that a participant gets dropped after each draw, consequently leading to a neat (too neat?) an expression of k/n as the probability of winning a gift card.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: $k$ people out of $n$ get prizes, so the answer is just $\frac kn$ unless I have misunderstood the rules.

Comment: Thanks! You might be correct, but I’m not being able to frame the reasoning correctly in my mind. See, if you have “n” balls of different colors C1….Cn, the probability of drawing a ball of a certain color Ci in the 1st draw is 1/n, but the independent probability of drawing a ball of a different color in the 2nd draw is not 1/n. I guess I’m struggling to see how we can arrive the k/n answer without taking the conditional probability route. For instance, what if we were to ask what is the probability that an individual can win in the 4th draw?

Comment: Each person is equally likely to win any given draw, so $\frac 1n$.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the conditional probability method, it's just unnecessary.  But $1-\left(\frac {n-1}n\times \frac {n-2}{n-1}\right)=1-\frac {n-2}{n}=\frac 2n$, just to write out the case $k=2$ as an example.

Comment: I say, it's much simpler to just note that each person is equally likely to win any of the prizes, and the events "winning prize $j$" are mutually exclusive so if there are $k$ prizes, the odds of winning one are $\frac 1n+\cdots +\frac 1n=\frac kn$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.